# Trying to create two different account types in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a simple donation app in rails. In this application, patrons would give amounts of money to clients. Both the patron and the client share large amounts of the same functionality. They are both linked to a user and have a username. However, the client is also supposed to have a `content_type` and a `content_list` property. At first glance, my guess is that I want to have both my patron and client inherit from the account class. However, the client has additional functionality, which seems to preclude any STI-based implementation (though I will be the first to admit that my understanding of STI is shaky at best). As it stands, it seems to simply make more sense to write out two separate resources, but I would like to keep my code as DRY as humanly possible. Is there a simple way for me to create the behaviors I want through inheritance, or should I simply go with overlapping resources?

Comment: Question to ask yourself before you go further... Could a patron ever be a client? Could a client ever be a patron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, as both of your user-types share the same basic functionalities.

As you said, make one make one unified `User` or `Account` model. Include the database fields `customer` (as boolean) and `patron` (also as boolean).

In the signup process, the user can then select if they're a patron or customer, as they would regardless.

Then inside your view, you can then call, if you use Devise for instance (which I personally think is great)

```
<% if current_user.patron == true %>
<!-- all relevant UI functionality for patrons -->
<% end %>
```

or if the User is a customer

```
<% if current_user.customer == true %>
<!-- all relevant UI functionality for customers -->
<% end %>
```

Or if you want to loop through a list of patrons or customers:

```
<% @user.where(:customer == true).each do |users| %>
   <% @user.first_name %> <% @user.last_name %>
<% end %>
```

These are just basic examples, but it would do just fine for what you're trying to achieve.

> P.S You could also create one migration called "account_type" as a
>   string and then with the help of radio_buttons in the signup process
>   store the account_type as a string value.
>
> ```
> <%= f.radio_button :account_type, "customer" %>
> <%= f.radio_button :account_type, "patron" %>
> ```
>
> I actually think that would be better. Then you would split the views up 
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <% if current_user.account_type => "customer" %>
> Show the list that only customer should have or see.
> <% end %>
>
>    <% if current_user.account_type => "patron" %>
>    Show the list that only patron should have or see.
>    <% end %>
>
>
>
> <% @user.where(:account_type => "customer").each do |users| %>
>   <% @user.first_name %> <% @user.last_name %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Comment: In this implementation, how would I handle the two unique data types which client has (the content type and a list of said content), but are absent from both the patron and the account resources?

Comment: You just add those datatypes to the User model, and then opt only to show it to the User with the corresponding account_type. I'll update the answer

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Am I correct to guess that this logic would be fired as part of the `create` method in my account controller?

Comment: Well, on account creation, when all the user information is saved to the Database, yes. But when you're showing a list of something you usually use the `index` action as in `def index` inside the controller together with a corresponding index.html.erb view.

Comment: This is ultimately what I ended up going with. I am currently hashing out the logic of account creation, but a single unified account resources has already saved me crazy amounts of double-typing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my question: Will a patron ever be a client? Will a client ever be a patron?

If the answer is "yes", you should consider creating a separate entity/model for the resource they're relating to.

With model DonationCampaign (attributes `client_id`, among others):

```
has_one :client, :class_name => 'User'
has_many :patrons, :class_name => 'DonationCampaignPatron'
```

DonationCampaignPatron (attributes `patron_id`, among others):

```
belongs_to :patron, :class_name => 'User'
```

This allows you to keep the shared functionality of User and then extend functionality to specific campaigns, without having to make other models messy, and keeps things DRY.

If a DonationCampaign could then have multiple users (as administrators, per se), to extend, a DonationCampaignRole model would be required, `donation_campaign_id`, `user_id`, `role`

Say you're using CanCanCan,

`if can? :manage, @campaign`

`if can? :contribute, @campaign`

`:contribute` would have to be added to ability.rb and could simply be `@campaign.client != User`

Also, STI example (the good kind, at least):

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def says
    raise "Implement on subclass"
  end  
end

class Cat < Animal
 # always has a type of 'Cat'
  def says
    "meow"
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
 # always has a type of 'Dog'
  def says
    "woof"
  end
end
```

And there's only one table: animals

Edit: Based on your response: From what I can learn by briefly using Patreon they have a single User model (for authentication), and then they likely have a creator_page_id in the User column. They then have a separate model CreatorPage which has all the "Client" (in your terms) info associated with it.

Personally, I would stick with a single User model for authentication and then implement the aforementioned DonationCampaign/DonationCampaignPatreon business logic. It's the most extensible with the least amount of effort (both long and shot-term).

If, for whatever reason, a Client is restricted to contributing to other Clients once they are a Client, I would forego using STI on the User model.

Comment: I honestly haven't thought about that. I am basically trying to recreate Patreon's model, where a single user sends money to a creator. In their model, there really appears to be no line between a creator and a patron once both account types have been initialized w/a given email. I suppose that would be what I had in mind. Ultimately, the actual functioning of the network is less important to me than the payment process, so whichever implementation gets this project to that point quicker would probably be my choice.

Comment: I have been building with two separate resources simply because I know how to do it. However, the functionality of the two resources is literally identical in almost every case. If for no other reason than saving time, I think that having a single account resource which gets modified in the event that it is a client account may be the way to go. In order to do this, would I want to emulate the animal example you gave?